# passing data back to main page using xamarin.forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I have 2 pages **product_page** and **novo_pedido_page**. when I'm in **novo_pedido_page** I have a button where i call **product_Page** to select one product from a grid. What I wanna do is, select this product and send back to **novo_pedido_page**.

What i've done so far is this on **novo_pedido_page**:

```
private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new product_page());
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use Event Handlers and Delegates:

In product_page you should send the event:

```
public event EventHandler<Product> ProductSelected;

private void Product_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var productId = ((Button) sender).CommandParameter;
    var product = GetProduct(productId);
    ProductSelected?.Invoke(this, product);
}
```

In novo_pedido_page you have to subscribe and handle this event :

```
private Product selectedProduct;

private async void ToolbarItem_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var page = new product_page();
    page.ProductSelected += OnProductSelected;
    await Navigation.PushModalAsync(page);
}


private void OnProductSelected(object sender, Product product)
{
    this.selectedProduct = product;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that did the trick i just add the parameters back to show on my list_view.